# How can I change the value put in text_field_tag written as full-width character by someone to half-width character on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on the project of platform.
And I am facing to the problem that I can't change the letter type written as full-width character to half-width character put on text_field_tag.

I want to change the number put in form, like １２３４　to 1234 when it sends request, because I want to enable someone who input number like １２３４ to search the number as 1234 on my database.

But I don't know where to start to solve this problem.
I only know that I can use str method to change the number.

Please kindly help me.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has a built-in [NKF extension](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/nkf/rdoc/NKF.html), you could convert full-width characters to half-width characters like this:

```rb
require 'nkf'

string = '１２３４'
NKF.nkf('-X -w', string).tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z') # => '1234'
```

Comment: thank you so much for your comment. this works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if this is your problem statement:

```
  i = "1 2 3 4"
  i.gsub(' ', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
but I actually looking for the way to change the full-width character which is different from 1234 this kind of number. or 1 2 3 4. it is large and need two spaces for one letter.